# How to get all sentences that contain multiple words in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a regular expressions to get all sentences containing two words (order doesn't matter), but I can't find the solution for this.

"Supermarket. This apple costs 0.99."

I want to get back the following sentence:

This apple costs 0.99.

I tried:

```
([^.]*?(apple)*?(costs)[^.]*\.)
```

I have problems because the price contains a dot. Also this expressions gives back results with only one of the words.

Comment: Why use regex and not just IN or Find?

Comment: @Ludo21South, IN or find would not work because it would match wrong words. For example, `apple` would find a match in `pineapple`.

Comment: Did any of the answers work out?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach:** For each Phrase, we have to find the sentences which contain all the words of the phrase. So, for each word in the given phrase, we check if a sentence contains it. We do this for each sentence. This process of searching may become faster if the words in the sentence are stored in a set instead of a list.

Below is the implementation of above approach in python:

```
def getRes(sent, ph): 
    sentHash = dict() 
  
    # Loop for adding hased sentences to sentHash 
    for s in range(1, len(sent)+1): 
        sentHash[s] = set(sent[s-1].split()) 
          
    # For Each Phrase 
    for p in range(0, len(ph)): 
        print("Phrase"+str(p + 1)+":") 
  
        # Get the list of Words 
        wordList = ph[p].split() 
        res = [] 
  
        # Then Check in every Sentence 
        for s in range(1, len(sentHash)+1): 
            wCount = len(wordList) 
  
            # Every word in the Phrase 
            for w in wordList: 
                if w in sentHash[s]: 
                    wCount -= 1
  
            # If every word in phrase matches 
            if wCount == 0: 
  
            # add Sentence Index to result Array 
                res.append(s) 
        if(len(res) == 0): 
            print("NONE") 
        else: 
            print('% s' % ' '.join(map(str, res))) 
  
# Driver Function 
def main(): 
    sent = ["Strings are an array of characters", 
    "Sentences are an array of words"] 
    ph = ["an array of", "sentences are strings"] 
    getRes(sent, ph) 
  
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a negated character class `[^.]` which matches any character except a dot.

But in your example data `Supermarket. This apple costs 0.99.` there are 2 dots before the dot at the end, so you can not cross the dot after `Supermarket.` to match `apple`

You could for example match until the first dot, then assert `costs` and use a capture group to match the part with `apple` and make sure the line ends with a dot.

The assertion for word 1 with a match for word 2 will match the words in both combinations.

```
^[^.]*\.\s*(?=.*\bcosts\b)(.*\bapple\b.*\.)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^[^.]*\.` From the start of the string, match until and including the first dot
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace character
- `(?=.*\bcosts\b)` Positive lookahead, assert `costs` at the right
- `(` Capture **group 1** *(this has the desired value)*

  - `.*\bapple\b.*\.` Match the rest of the line that includes `apple` and ends with a dot
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t643Rq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/e33aQ5)

```
import re

regex = r"^[^.]*\.\s*(?=.*\bcosts\b)(.*\bapple\b.*\.)$"
test_str = ("Supermarket. This apple costs 0.99.\n"
    "Supermarket. This costs apple 0.99.\n"
    "Supermarket. This apple is 0.99.\n"
    "Supermarket. This orange costs 0.99.")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['This apple costs 0.99.', 'This costs apple 0.99.']
```

Comment: This solution doesn't break into sentences correctly. Consider [this example](https://regex101.com/r/t643Rq/4).

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Yes that is correct, but that is not the example data.

Comment: In that case, you can for example match not dot, except when it is followed by a digit. `(?<!\S)(?=(?:[^.]|\.(?=\d))*\bapple\b)(?:[^.]|\.(?=\d))*\bcosts\b(?:[^.]|\.(?=\d))*\.` https://regex101.com/r/zkDe6s/1

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to first extract sentences and then find sentences that have both words.

However, the problem of splitting text into sentences is pretty hard because of existence of abbreviations, unusual names, etc. One way to do it is by using [`nltk.tokenize.punkt`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) module.

You'll need to install NLTK and then run this in Python:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

After that you can use English language sentence tokenizer with two regexes:

```
TEXT = 'Mr. Bean is in supermarket. iPhone 12 by Apple Inc. costs $999.99.'
WORD1 = 'apple'
WORD2 = 'costs'

import nltk.data, re

# Regex helper
find_word = lambda w, s: re.search(r'(^|\W)' + w + r'(\W|$)', s, re.I)

eng_sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
for sent in eng_sent_detector.tokenize(TEXT):
    if find_word(WORD1, sent) and find_word(WORD2, sent):
        print (sent,"\n----")
```

Output:

```
iPhone 12 by Apple Inc. costs $999.99.
----
```

Notice that it handles numbers and abbreviations for you.